# Show pdf file into browser without Adobe Reader

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-viewer

I need to open pdf file into browser without Adobe Reader. Is there any API with php which open PDF files into browser.

Regards

Comment: As long as I know, there is no way to display a PDF in the browser, without PDF-Viewing Engine like Adobe Reader, except when you reneder the pdf to html (like google-docs does). But I don't know any library which does this. Maybe there is one (maybe googles is open-source) - I am interested too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) to convert PDFs to Flash. But SWFTools default skins are not looking good at all, so you can check [Flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com) as a viewer.
In case you are going to make your own skin, then could be useful to read: [SWFTools (pdf2swf) to properly work with Flex](http://www.igorcosta.org/?p=231)

Another solution is pdf.js (as Quentin point out), but AFAIR this script was not usable(back then, when I looked for) for PDFs with complex structures (complex gradients for example).

If you need to publish documents as "private" you should look at services as [Issuu](http://issuu.com/) or you will have to protect files from downloading.

Answer (score 2):

No.

PHP runs on the server. The only "browser API" it has access to is HTTP.

If you want to render a PDF on the client, then the client needs a PDF renderer. There are [JavaScript PDF readers](http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/), but I can't comment on their cross-browser support or maturity.

Answer (score 1):

If you pdf files are put online and not restricted, you can try using Google Doc Viewer. It's a very nice way to put the Viewer in `<iframe />` so that it can be combined with your web page.

> https://docs.google.com/viewer

Answer (score 0):

It is not feasible to view the PDF files without a viewer like Adobe Reader. If you just don't want to use Adobe Reader, you may try a PDF viewer plug in for web browser from some other company.

However, if you do not want to use a viewer at all and want to write/build your own viewer then a better option is to convert the PDF to scalable images and then show them on the web page using image tags. You can also create such a viewer using JavaScript.

Even you can find many already available JavaScript based viewers which can show those images.